# Persist JWT tokens on static web pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, serverless

Currently running a website with aws lambda and api gateway.The website is ran with node.js in a s3 bucket.

I manage to generate a JWT token for the user, however I would not like to store it in cookies etc.

My current setup, is that if user wants to use dynamo, he goes into one table and retrieves the token, which is then used to get data from another table.

The problem is that I have to make two requests each time, one to validate the token or fetch it, and the other to do the request

Comment: You _don't_ want to store it in a cookie?  Why not?  The whole point of JWT is that it's signed on the server side, and the client sends it with each request.  For the client to send it, they have to have it.  Then the server verifies it's not tampered with.  So store in in LocalStorage, or SessionStorage-- you still have to check it on the server, but the client has to have a copy.

Comment: @MattMorgan I did not want to deal with the possible security flaws that cookies pose.

Do you know of the best practice, if it is cookie storing then there must be a way to secure it?

Also, if It gets set in the header, how long does it persist for?

Thanks Matt

Comment: I've tried to address your concerns in my answer.  Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security of a JWT comes from the fact that it's generated and signed on  your server with a secret key that the client doesn't have.  You can, for example, set an expiration date, add the user's username or IP address to the claims, or whatever you want to add.

Any claims you embed in the token *cannot* be changed without invalidating the signature of the JWT.  **This is a key concept.**

The only security risk you have of putting the JWT in to a cookie (or a header, or local storage, or session storage, or embedding it as JSON in the webpage for example) is that someone *other* than your authorized user can get it and use it.  There are various ways they could do that-- man in the middle attack, XSS, etc.

If the token has an expiration date, and is tied to the user's IP address then only requests from that IP for the allowed duration will be valid.  The durability of a cookie is not relevant if you're checking your JWT for an expiration date that you set.

But again, the user has to have the token to send it, so you have to store it somewhere on their side, and a cookie is as good a place as any.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You’ve saved me a good couple of days, maybe even a week. I can send a notification to a users phone on each edit or save and notify them if someone is using their token, or I can check for a change in IP address and also notify. Thanks again Matt.. Also there would be no way to invalidate the token I guess, so setting TTL to short time would be only counter attack to man in the middle. Thanks again Matt for the perfect explanation

Comment: No worries! You could store every token in your Dynamo table, with a hash of the value, or a UUID maybe (which could be part of the token claims.)  If you wanted to revoke it you could mark it as such or remove it, either way.

Comment: Yeah that’s a good idea, can make periodic calls to dynamo along with requests, so if users are hacked the token can be revoked within 3 minutes for example. Or have some functionality in the authoriser function. Just don’t want to over do on the db requests. Thank you Matt, this has solved my problem at last, thank you